# Programming a ZED camera in C++

Tags: c++, linux, object, hardware

The UAV flies in an environment and it equips with a dual lens camera(ZED stereo camear) in front of an UAV. This camera is responsible for detecting the environment and it can offer the depth information of the environment and generate the point cloud of the environment. The generated point will have for origin the ZED camera itself. There is no obstacle detection in the SDK, but you can loop over the point cloud looking for points a less than 5 meters for example. If you detect a group of point, you can consider this as an obstacle positioned in the ZED referential. With this program(main.cpp) you can achieve the 3d coordinates(the origin is in the middle of left len, x is horizontal axis, y is vertically downward, z axis is the distance between camera and point cloud ) of point cloud on real time when UAV is flying. This program is modified by my partner. So it is a little bit different from the original one what it is offered by official website.

```
Continue to program in C++ and commend each line.
Tasks are:
The view field of this camera is 110 degree. But I will not use all of them. So define a view field at 30 degree of camera. When the camera detects the groups of point cloud in this 30 degree within 5m, the program gives an alarm and return a command to control system to make UAV hover. You should continue to program the main.cpp.
In the end you should give me 2 programs: 1 is with alarm, the other is with a command to control system. I do not need any report.
I will run this program in JETSON TX1 platform in Ubuntu, later maybe it will involve in some debugs process, but no problem, I will try my best to debug, if somewhere I cannot deal with, I will ask you for help.
This topic has a set of tasks, this is the first one, if you work well, we can talk about the others.

What I can offer you are:
globaldefined.hpp
Camera.hpp
Mat.hpp
Main.cpp
```

All the information about this camera is under: https://www.stereolabs.com/zed/specs/

```
Suppose UAV data:
Length:1500mm
Width:1500mm
Height:500mm
Speed:1000mm/s
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need help with coming up with an algorithm for the said camera controls